# Spark structured streaming container killed with foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I've a spark structured streaming process reading from kafka and writing to another kafka topic. I'm calling foreachParttion on a DataFrame to construct a json payload and POST to a REST endpoint. The reason I prefer foreachpartition over foreach, because I don't want to iterate over each row and do a http call. Below code works fine for me in my local unit test, however when I run using spark-submit in yarn with `--deploy-mode cluster` it fails with container killed. My class is Serializable.

Appreciate any help here.

```
    def postData(groupName: String, errorDF: DataFrame): Try[String] = {
      var response: String = ""
      errorDFforeachPartition(partition => {
        partition.foreach(row => {
          val jsonString =  "[" + row.mkString(",").replace("WrappedArray(", "").replace(")", "") + "]"
          response = ServiceParser.postResponse(groupName, serviceConfig, jsonString)
          response = apiResponse match {
            case Success(value) => value
            case Failure(exception) => throw exception
          }
        })
      })
    Try(response)
  }
```

Container Log

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
.
Driver stacktrace:
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2041)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2029)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
 scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
 scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2028)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
 scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2262)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2211)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2200)
 org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
 org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
 org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
 org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
 org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
 org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:933)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:933)
 com.etl.service.ExceptionResponseHelper.postData(ExceptionResponseHelper.scala:74)
 com.etl.service.CommonExceptionServiceProcessor$$anonfun$postDataAndRetryOnError$1.apply(CommonExceptionServiceProcessor.scala:368)
 com.etl.service.CommonExceptionServiceProcessor$$anonfun$postDataAndRetryOnError$1.apply(CommonExceptionServiceProcessor.scala:368)
 com.etl.service.ServiceRetryUtil$.retryOnError(ServiceRetryUtil.scala:17)
 com.etl.service.CommonExceptionServiceProcessor.postDataAndRetryOnError(CommonExceptionServiceProcessor.scala:367)
 com.etl.service.ExceptionServiceProcessor.postDataToExceptionService(ExceptionServiceProcessor.scala:781)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlExceptionFlow.processExceptions(EtlExceptionFlow.scala:67)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlExceptionFlow.process(EtlExceptionFlow.scala:32)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlFlow$$anonfun$runSingleBatch$1.apply(EtlFlow.scala:51)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlFlow$$anonfun$runSingleBatch$1.apply(EtlFlow.scala:47)
 com.common.AutoClosing$$anonfun$1.apply(AutoClosing.scala:8)
 scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
 com.common.AutoClosing$class.autoClose(AutoClosing.scala:8)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlFlow.autoClose(EtlFlow.scala:13)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlFlow.runSingleBatch(EtlFlow.scala:46)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlFlow$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(EtlFlow.scala:39)
 com.etl.common.etlflow.EtlFlow$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(EtlFlow.scala:38)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:35)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:537)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:535)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:534)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:281)
 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)","exception_class":"org.apache.spark.SparkException","exception_message":"Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 610.0 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.7 in stage 610.0 (TID 60746, ip-10-223-10-210.ec2.internal, executor 14): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 14 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1630278892891_0610_01_000022 on host: ip-10-223-10-210.ec2.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1630278892891_0610_01_000022
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
 org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
 org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
 org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:235)
 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

NodeManager Log

```
2021-09-03 00:37:17,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl (Node Status Updater): Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1630278892891_0527_01_000011]
2021-09-03 00:37:41,439 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor (ContainersLauncher #28): Exit code from container container_1630278892891_0512_02_000001 is : 15
2021-09-03 00:37:41,439 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor (ContainersLauncher #28): Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1630278892891_0512_02_000001 and exit code: 15
ExitCodeException exitCode=15: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```